# JSOUP for getting table row index

Tags: parsing, jsoup

Can someone please help on how this can be implemented using JSOUP. I am trying to know the position of `src="images/myimage.png"` in their respective `tr` tag as I plan to put this in DB.

[Sample html tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0qfs.png)

I have a basic code to traverse the elements

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("dummy.html").get();

    for (Element body : html_data.getElementsByTag("body")) {
        System.out.println(body.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(Element body:rfs_table.getElementsByTag("tbody")) {


         Elements tr =body.getElementsByTag("tr");

         for(int x=0;x<tr.size();x++) {

             Element row = tr.get(x);
             Elements cols = row.select("td");

             int c=0;
             for(Element a:cols) {

                 if(a.hasClass("tbl1")) {
                     System.out.println(a.toString() + "with image");
                 }else {
                     System.out.println(a.toString() + c);
                 }

                 c++;
             }
         }
```

This is the solution I was able to come up with.